# Positioning a small image on the left edge of a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am placing a vertical image into a square UIImageView. It gets centered inside the square. Does UIImageView have a method to shift its contained image to the right or left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could try:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
```

Otherwise I would recommend just putting the image view where you want it.